# Longest Diagonal Length of Regular Polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons

I don't have so knowledge about mathematics. Thus, this question may be so stupid. If so I will delete question.

I'm curious about is there a way to find longest diagonal length of a regular polygon without using any theorem and calculation related to circle?

Comment: Just check what happens with square, pentagon, hexagon, etc and try to find a patter for odd and pair number of sides.

Comment: I use pythagorean relation till decagon for pair number of side but I should use sin and cos. This calculation I think related to circle.

Comment: Have you found the answer some other way that uses theorems and calculations related to the circle? I can't immediately see a way to do it without using something like Law of Sines.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-longest-diagonal-in-a-regular-polygon-when-it-has-an-odd-number-of-sides